# How to reduce PhantomJS's CPU and memory usage?

Tags: phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS via Python's webdriver lib. It eats lots of RAM and CPU, and it's an issue because I'd like to run as many instances as it's possible.

Some google'ing didn't give me anything helpful. So I'll ask directly:

1. Does the size matter? If I set driver.set_window_size(1280, 1024), will it eat more memory than 1024x768?
2. Is there any option in the source code which can be turned off without real issues and which lead to significant memory usage reduce? Yes I still need images and CSS and JS loading and applying, but I can get rid of some other features... For example, I can turn off caching (and load all media files every time). Yes, I do need to speed it up and make it less greedy and I'm ready to re-compile it... Any ideas here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm having the same issue here, but not having valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you call phantomjs once for every rendering job. This creates a new phantomjs process every time. You could try batching as many as you could in the one js script and call phantomjs once for the whole batch.

Comment: no, I scrape many pages using every instance. I do not restart phantomjs every time for scraping a single page.

Comment: I'm also aware of the memory leaking bug so I do restart the instances from time to time, getting the optimal performance\memory consumption ratio. So the memory is not a big issue, though it would be nice to reduce it, anyway. But the CPU usage is the worst thing - it's relatively high even if I load simple pages with minimum of JS.